# How to do a (trapeze) integration in Python with x^2?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math, numerical-integration

My task is to do first an integration and second a trapezoid integration with Python of **f(x)=x^2**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(-10,10)   
y = x**2

l=plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show(l)
```

[image]

Now I want to integrate this function to get this: **F(x)=(1/3)x^3** with the picture:

[image]

This should be the output in the end:

[image]

Could someone explain me how to get the antiderivative F(x) of f(x)=x^2 with python?
I want to do this with a normal integration and a trapeze integration. For trapezoidal integration from (-10 to 10) and a step size of 0.01 (width of the trapezoids). In the end I want to get the function F(x)=(1/3)x^3 in both cases. How can I reach this?

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: I guess you could start by googling: https://hplgit.github.io/edu/py_vs_m/._numerical_programming_guide001.html https://www.math.ubc.ca/~pwalls/math-python/integration/trapezoid-rule/ https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html

Comment: I have already googled it but I couldn't find what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

There are two key observations:

- the trapezoidal rule refers to numeric integration, whose output is not an integral function but a number
- integration is up to an arbitrary constant which is not included in your definition of `F(x)`

With this in mind, you can use [`scipy.integrate.trapz()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.trapz.html#scipy.integrate.trapz) to define an integral function:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import trapz


def numeric_integral(x, f, c=0):
    return np.array([sp.integrate.trapz(f(x[:i]), x[:i]) for i in range(len(x))]) + c
```

or, more efficiently, using [`scipy.integrate.cumtrapz()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.cumtrapz.html#scipy.integrate.cumtrapz) (which does the computation from above):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import cumtrapz


def numeric_integral(x, f, c=0):
    return cumtrapz(f(x), x, initial=c)
```

This plots as below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def func(x):
    return x ** 2


x = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.01)
y = func(x)
Y = numeric_integral(x, func)

plt.plot(x, y, label='f(x) = x²')
plt.plot(x, Y, label='F(x) = x³/3 + c')
plt.plot(x, x ** 3 / 3, label='F(x) = x³/3')
plt.legend()
```

which provides you the desidered result except for the arbitrary constant, which you should specify yourself.

[image: plot]

For good measure, while not relevant in this case, note that `np.arange()` does not provide stable results if used with a fractional step. Typically, one would use `np.linspace()` instead.

Comment: why you use c=0? Can I leave that out?

Comment: @mathflower Of course you can leave that out. It is just to account for the proper math which says that the integral function is defined up to an arbitrary constant, `c` in code.

Comment: I only asked this because you manually inserted the antiderivative of x**2 instead of having it calculated. So you have calculated the antiderivative but with a constant c. And I only wanted to have the antiderivative without c.

Comment: @mathflower I am not sure what you are referring to. The code in `numeric_integral()` knows nothing about `f()` to begin with. I just plot the analytical result for completeness, and nothing more. The existence of `c` has mathematical significance. Its value in this numerical approach only depends on the actual `x` you use. There is no mathematically valid way of obtaining a value of `c` that always matches what you have in your *analytical anti-derivative* found using the rules you studies in calculus for any arbitrary function and `x` range considered.

Comment: @mathflower In other words, you want to have `c = 0`, but what you get is `c = F(x0)` with `x0` lower extreme of `x`. Since you (have to pretend you) do not know `F(x)`, you cannot compute `c` explicitly.

Comment: Ah okay. I think I understand what you mean. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The `cumtrapz` function from scipy will provide an antiderivative using trapezoid integration:

```
from scipy.integrate import cumtrapz
yy = cumtrapz(y, x, initial=0)

# make yy==0 around x==0 (optional)
i_x0 = np.where(x >= 0)[0][0]
yy -= yy[i_x0]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Trapezoid integration**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.1)
f = x**2

F = [-333.35]
for i in range(1, len(x) - 1):
    F.append((f[i] + f[i - 1])*(x[i] - x[i - 1])/2 + F[i - 1])
F = np.array(F)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, f)
ax.plot(x[1:], F)

plt.show()
```

Here I have applied the theoretical formula `(f[i] + f[i - 1])*(x[i] - x[i - 1])/2 + F[i - 1]`, while the integration is done in the block:

```
F = [-333.35]
for i in range(1, len(x) - 1):
    F.append((f[i] + f[i - 1])*(x[i] - x[i - 1])/2 + F[i - 1])
F = np.array(F)
```

**Note** that, in order to plot `x` and `F`, they must have the same number of element; so I ignore the first element of `x`, so they both have `199` element. This is a result of the *trapezoid metho*d: if you integrate an array `f` of `n` elements, you obtain an array `F` of `n-1` elements. Moreover, I set the initial value of `F` to `-333.35` at `x = -10`, this is the arbitrary constant from the integration process, I decided that value in order to pass the function near the origin.

---

**Analytical integration**

```
import sympy as sy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = sy.symbols('x')
f = x**2
F = sy.integrate(f, x)

xv = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.1)
fv = sy.lambdify(x, f)(xv)
Fv = sy.lambdify(x, F)(xv)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(xv, fv)
ax.plot(xv, Fv)

plt.show()
```

Here I use the symbolic math through `sympy` module. The integration is done in the block:

```
F = sy.integrate(f, x)
```

**Note** that, in this case, `F` and `x` have already the same number of elements. Moreover, the code is simpler.

Comment: Note that your use of the trapezoidal integration is not correct. You can see it by plotting `x ** 3 / 3`.

Comment: Could you explain me that line, please: (f[i] + f[i - 1])*(x[i] - x[i - 1])/2 + F[i - 1]

Comment: @mathflower That is the formula for the area of the trapezium between the x-axis and the function plus the sum of all previos trapezia.

Comment: As already said by @norok2, in that formula you sum the major and minor bases of the trapeze (`f[i]` and `f[i - 1]`), multiply it by the trapeze's height (`x[i] - x[i - 1]`) and divide by 2, which is the formula for the area of a trapeze. Finally, you sum this result to the previous one `F[i - 1]`

Comment: How did you come up with F[-333.35]? Can I take another value?

Comment: I chosen this value to pass the function near the origin. It is my arbitrary choice and you can choose another value. It is the constant of integration that come with the integration process